# Huge amount of files in Fortify / Apache Tomcat temp directory

Tags: tomcat, windows-server-2019, temporary-files

We are running a commercial software app (Fortify) on Apache Tomcat. We've asked the vendor, but so far no usable response. So I'm posting this here in case it's an issue with the underlying Apache Tomcat platform:

We've been observing that the Fortify Security Control Center (SSC) (currently 23.1, but it has happened for many versions), running on Windows 2019 Datacenter, generates a lot of files in the Apache Tomcat 11 temp directory (`<Tomcat rootdir>/temp`). The files all have a filename like this pattern `crl<number>.tmp` (i.e. `crl210960993782028638.tmp`) and are zero (0) bytes (so empty). Every day more than 1000 files are generated!

We currently run a scheduled script that removes all those files older than 12 hours, otherwise the disk will fill up with lots of small files. When we first encountered this, we actually had to delete several millions of those files, which fully choked up Windows.

Any idea what may be causing this? Their prefix "crl" seems to imply it has to do with a Certificate Revocation List. We can't find any clue in the logging. We also checked using Process Monitor and the files are created by the Fortify SSC tomcat Windows Service wrapper app (which is the official Tomcat Windows Service wrapper). Inspecting its stack didn't give any additional clues.

Does anybody have any idea what might cause this? Any clue how to further debug?

Comment: what are the contents of the crl files? If they are cached revocation lists, they should start with `-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----`. Sometimes tomcat can be told to enable crl checking with a system property like `-Dcom.sun.security.enableCRLDP=true`. The number of CRLs it caches would depend on how many different CAs it's verifying certificates against

Comment: They are zero bytes / no contents. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found the culprit. A piece of Fortify code creates those temp files and doesn't clean them up properly. As this is vendor-specific code I'll close this issue here. Let's hope the vendor will fix this.